# Solve equation with complex conjugate

Tags: maxima

When I try to do this:

```
(%i1) declare (z, complex);
(%o1)                                done
(%i2) eq1: z^3 + 3 * %i * conjugate(z) = 0;
                                               3
(%o2)                     3 %i conjugate(z) + z  = 0
(%i3) solve(eq1, z);
                  1/6   5/6       1/3              1/3
             (- 1)    (3    %i - 3   ) conjugate(z)
(%o3) [z = - -----------------------------------------, 
                                 2
         1/6   5/6       1/3              1/3
    (- 1)    (3    %i + 3   ) conjugate(z)
z = -----------------------------------------, 
                        2
           1/6  1/3             1/3
z = - (- 1)    3    conjugate(z)   ]
```

conjugates are not simplified.  And the solution for `z` in terms of `z` isn't very useful.  Is there a way to simplify it?

Also, how can I simplify out the `(-1)^(1/6)` part?

Also, this equation clearly has `0` as its root, but it's not in the solution set, why?

Comment: For the record, I see that `to_poly_solve` (which see) can solve some equations containing `conjugate`. For the example given here, it just makes a big mess, but maybe it's more useful for other problems.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier that's useful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `solve` knows anything about `conjugate`. Try this to solve it with the real and imaginary parts of `z` as two variables. Like this:

```
(%i2) declare ([zr, zi], real) $
(%i3) z : zr + %i*zi $
(%i4) eq1: z^3 + 3 * %i * conjugate(z) = 0;
(%o4) (zr+%i*zi)^3+3*%i*(zr-%i*zi) = 0
(%i5) solve (eq1, [zr, zi]);
(%o5) [[zr = %r1,
        zi = (sqrt(9*%r1^2-%i)+3*%r1)^(1/3)-%i/(sqrt(9*%r1^2-%i)+3*%r1)^(1/3)
                                           +%i*%r1],
       [zr = %r2,
        zi = ((sqrt(3)*%i)/2-1/2)*(sqrt(9*%r2^2-%i)+3*%r2)^(1/3)
           -(%i*((-(sqrt(3)*%i)/2)-1/2))/(sqrt(9*%r2^2-%i)+3*%r2)^(1/3)
           +%i*%r2],
       [zr = %r3,
        zi = ((-(sqrt(3)*%i)/2)-1/2)*(sqrt(9*%r3^2-%i)+3*%r3)^(1/3)
           -(%i*((sqrt(3)*%i)/2-1/2))/(sqrt(9*%r3^2-%i)+3*%r3)^(1/3)+%i*%r3]]
```

Note the variables`%r1`, `%r2`, and `%r3` in the solution. These represent arbitrary values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But, to be honest, I'm not very happy with this as a solution. This gives imaginary part in terms of real part, if I understand this correctly... Perhaps there's a way to do it in polar form? I'd expect this to produce a result close to `-3^(1/3)cis(%pi/2) + k * %pi`.

Comment: Well, you can put it back together via `ev(z : zr + %i*zi, zr = %r3, zi = <long expression>);` and then try simplifying that via `radcan` and `polarform`. But when I try that I get a pretty big mess.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks for the effort though!